# how could i change color and size of primeng-paginator

Tags: css, angular, primeng, paginator

I am using prime-ng paginator in my project and I want to change its color and size of paginator. I am trying to fix it with diff ways but it's not working for me.

below is my code :

************ .CSS file ***********

`
:host ::ng-deep .p-paginator {

color: #033335;

}
.custom-paginator .ui-paginator-page {

font-size: 36px;

*color: #333;*
`

************* .html file************

```
<div style="flex: 1 0 auto; margin-left: 10%">          
<p-paginator
          class="custom-paginator"
            [rows]="10"
            
          ></p-paginator>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your.component.html:

```
<p-paginator class="custom-paginator" [rows]="10"></p-paginator>
```

In your.component.css:

```
.custom-paginator .p-paginator {
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

The result should be something like this:
[image]